# what is the stabilization of pointed sets?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Given a(n $\infty$-)category, there is a process called "stabilitazion" which spits out a stable $\infty$-category (as one can read about in either Higher Algebra or the nlab).

The famous example is Spectra, which is the stabilization of Top (and I guess the various enhancements of derived categories, out of categories of modules).

If I start instead with the plain old category of pointed sets, what is its stabilization? And if I start with finite pointed sets?

Comment: If you take the nerve of the category of pointed sets, then the suspension (and the based loops) of any object is the terminal object. So the stabilization is the trivial, stable oo-category with a single object (up to equivalence): The zero object.

Comment: So it's like saying: In the space of pointed oo-categories, pointed sets (and strict categories in general) are very singular points. Their tangent space is zero.

Comment: @HiroLeeTanaka: bummer. The reason I was wondering is that for some people the category of pointed sets should be the category of vector spaces over the field with one element. I guess to get to a category of complexes one should go about it in a different way. thanks.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but stabilizing a strict category doesn't magically create something with homotopically meaningful structure. For instance, the oo-category of chain complexes is not the stabilization of abelian groups. You need a separate construction (e.g., define the notion of a chain complex) to create homotopical structures.

Comment: @HiroLeeTanaka: ah, so that's where my ignorance of homotopy stuff shows. So, spectra objects in chain complexes produces the (enhanced) derived category? I guess the real question is then how to produce chain complexes in the first place.

Comment: The "nonabelian" analogue of a chain complex is generally considered to be a simplicial object.  So in your example, you would consider simplicial objects in pointed sets, a.k.a. pointed simplicial sets, and then stabilize to get the usual category of spectra.

Comment: @MikeShulman: that actually makes a lot of sense. thanks.

Comment: @HiroLeeTanaka: Your answer seems convincing, but I would like to have more details. Any 1-category satsifying the pull-iff-push axiom of a stable $\infty$-category must be trivial; but in $\infty$-categorical setting you're taking *homotopy* colimits to do suspension. I don't see how the maps $*\leftarrow X\to *$ can be cofibrations in an intuitive model structure on sets (there shouldn't be so many..)

Comment: @tetrapharmakon The (discrete) model structure on $\mathbf{Set}$ has isomorphisms for weak equivalences, so _every_ morphism is both a cofibration and a fibration. Moreover limits/colimits in $\mathbf{Set}$ considered as a quasicategory coincide with the ordinary notion.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon, in general, if $C$ is a cocomplete and complete 1-category then its nerve $N(C)$ is the infinity-category generated by the trivial model structure on $C$.

Comment: @Adeel: I didn't know about this result, thank you! (of course the answer was trivial if you take isomorphisms; I was wondering if for "the other eight" model structures the same argument hold).

Comment: @tetrapharmakon The other model structures are not relevant: they are models for homotopy $(-1)$-types or $(-2)$-types, so the corresponding quasicategories are weakly categorically equivalent to either $\Delta^1$ or $\Delta^0$.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon, the notion of "homotopy colimit" isn't required in the oo-category setting. (When I say oo-category, I mean a specific notion: weak Kan complexes). If the oo-category arises as the nerve of a simplicial model category, the notion of a homotopy co/limit coincides with that of a co/limit in the oo-category, but independent of any model-categorical theory, there is a well-defined notion of limits and colimits for oo-categories. The nerve of any strict category is in particular an oo-category, and co/limits of the oo-category coincide with those of the original category.

Comment: I was used to call both notions, invariably, "homotopy co/limit" because of this identification. But I admit my terminology can be non standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the comments: the stabilization is the trivial stable category.